# Including ES6 and Webpack with spring boot

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, es6-promise, babeljs

I have a spring boot application to modify and deploy in an existing Tomcat Server. App uses 1.5.4 version and thymeleaf, Jquery (4) and bootstrap for the front end. Front end accessing the controllers directly in some cases and rest apis.

I do have a resource constraint for production deployment, no separate servers available, app needs to run in tomcat. Don't have an option of separating front end & backend and use a frontend node server.

I want to include webpack or babel / es6 to the front end scripting (to take advantage of the features and use the features like Promises) - to address some of the complex AJAX calls callback async issues.  I googled and read, so many options. Appreciate any guidance and steps on how to do this

Comment: I feel like there is some confusion here.  Webpack is software used to build a project into files that would be used by the server.  It's not something that you would provide to a webpage directly, as far as I am aware.

Comment: If all you are really after is trying to guarantee that your users have ES6 methods available, like Promises, you might look first at trying to include an ECMAScript 6 shim in your application before you go making more big changes.  https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim

Answer (score 4):

There's probably a couple of ways you can do it, but if you happen to be using Gradle you can try the following solution:

1. Add node plugin in your build.gradle script:

   ```
   plugins {
     id "com.moowork.node" version "1.2.0"
   }
   ```
2. (Optional) configure the plugin (see: https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md)

   ```
   node {
     version = '8.11.3'
     npmVersion = '5.6.0'
     download = true
   }
   ```
3. Define npm task that runs the webpack and make sure it's executed prior to processing resources

   ```
   task webpack(type: NodeTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
       script = project.file('node_modules/.bin/webpack')
   }

   processResources.dependsOn 'webpack'
   ```
4. Configure webpack so that it outputs to some specific folder. For consistency with gradle, you can output it some folder inside `build/` folder:

   ```
   const path = require('path');
   const ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp');
   const DEST = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/fe');

   module.exports = {
     entry: [
       path.resolve(ROOT, 'js/scripts.js')
     ],
     output: {
       path: DEST,
       filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
     },
     // ...
   }
   ```
5. make sure that the output from the webpack is then processed as resources by gradle build:

   ```
   processResources {
     with copySpec {
       from "${buildDir}/fe"
       include "**/*.js"
       into "static"
     }
   }
   ```

Here is a sample repository that demonstrates the complete solution:

https://github.com/xmcax/thymleaf-demo

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate frontend from backend sources either to separate Maven/Gradle modules, or just put frontend related stuff into `src/main/frontend`.

Then you need to modify your build process:

- **Maven** - consider using [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) - it will download Node, NPM, and execute NPM task
- **Gradle** - last time I was playing with it [com.moowork.node](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.moowork.node) plugin was the thing, but things could have changed since then. You can take a look at my setup at that time here: https://github.com/maciejwalkowiak/spring-boot-react

Maven/Gradle should put your frontend `build` directory into static resources exposed by Spring Boot.

Good luck!